# Screen doesn't turn off after firmware upgrade

Tags: display, dell

I've always been able to turn the screen off by lowering the screen brightness. The last step would turn the screen off.

But since I recently did a firmware upgrade using fwupdmgr this doesn't work anymore. The screen's brightness simply goes one level lower.

The device which I upgraded:

```
UEFI-124c207d-5db8-4d95-bd31-34fd971b34f9-dev0
  Guid:                 124c207d-5db8-4d95-bd31-34fd971b34f9
  DisplayName:          XPS 15 9550
  Provider:             UEFI
  Flags:                internal|allow-offline|require-ac
  Version:              0.1.4.0
  VersionLowest:        0.1.4.0
  Created:              2017-10-22
  Trusted:              none
```

I have a Dell XPS 15 9550 running Loki.

`/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` contains 1 at the lowest brightness. I can fill it with 0 manually, which does turn the screen off, I just can't do that with my brightness keys.
`cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness` contains 1500.

Is anyone experiencing the same issue? Is this changeable in configuration maybe?

Answer (score 1):

So I wouldn't really call this a solution, more a workaround.

I did some research on how I could control my display, found interesting answers in: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/62858/turn-off-monitor-using-command-line
`xset` for example would always turn off all screens. 
`xrandr` seemed to also log me out sometimes
Both the the above would be canceled on key presses and mouse movement. They also seemed to be overruled by Redshift.

Then I learned about `xbacklight` from: https://askubuntu.com/a/149265/519324.
After a `sudo apt install xbacklight` I could control the brightness like I hoped. 
The following would set the brightness (of my main display) to actual 0 and let me turn it up again with my regular brightness meta keys.

`xbacklight -set 0`

So now I've put that command under the  keyboard shortcut: <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Monitor brightness down</kbd>.

I couldn't overrule my regular `Monitor brightness down`, for some reason `Disabled` would be shown.

I also learned using `xbacklight -get` that the lowest brightness I could reach with just the brightness meta keys was `0.066667`.

A better solution would be to make sure the brightness controlling meta keys could simply lower to 0...

**Update**: It appears that there have been lot's of discussions on whether screens should turn off at the lowest brightness. 
https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-power-manager/issues/179#issuecomment-170062936
There doesn't really seem to be a clear way to configure this...

**Update 2**: It's been a while, but sadly after a bios update using [fwupdmgr](https://fwupd.org/lvfs/docs/users) the `xbacklight` command stopped having any effect.